# What is the difference between these Jquery examples?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've seen various ways to attach event handlers using JQueryy and although each seem to work, I'm just not sure if they are at all different or if either are deprecated.

```
$(document).on("click", ".someSelector", function (event) {
  // do work...
});

$(function () {
  $(".someSelector").click(function (event) {
    // do work...
  });
});
```

Comment: Neither are deprecated.  They serve different purposes.

Comment: It's explained in the documentation on the [`.on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on/) method -> _"Direct and delegated event handlers"_

Comment: https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first example works whether or not there's an element on the page with class "someSelector".  If one is added eventually, it'll work.

The second only applies the event handler to existing elements. If an element is added later, "click" events won't be handled.

Comment: Exactly the information I was looking for.  That distinction is key in what I'm doing. Thanks!